# API setup Considerations with Informatica - Sandbox Refresh

Tags: api, integration, sandbox-refresh, informatica

I am trying to set up an API based integration b/w SFDC and Informatica on my Sandbox. What considerations do I have to keep in mind about Sandbox refresh?
e.g. If the sandbox gets refreshed, does that impact things that we’ve configured in the sandbox…such as would it remove the API we setup in the sandbox to test the automation of user management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would lose the existing setup on the refreshed sandbox . It's better to create these setting on production then create a sandbox of prod so that you always have one copy of setup in prod

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_status.htm&type=0&language=en_US